# Развернуть приложение на определенном порту в wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly

По-умолчанию, приложения в wildfly деплоятся по адресу `localhost:8080/app`, как развернуть приложение на каком-то отдельном порту без названия самого приложения, например, чтобы оно открывалось по адресу `localhost:8282`?

Answer (score 5):

Вся конфигурация Wildfly находится в domain*.xml или standalone*.xml файлах.
Пример для standalone.xml и Wildfly10:

открываем `%JBOSS_HOME%/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`
В теге `socket-binding-group` добавляем помимо `http` и `https` добавляем `http2` и `https2`

```
<!--Стандартные биндинги-->
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<!--Добавленные биндинги-->
<socket-binding name="http2" port="${jboss.http.port:8089}"/>
<socket-binding name="https2" port="${jboss.https.port:8449}"/>
```

Далее ищем `urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0` и добавляем новый сервер:

```
<!--Сервер по умолчанию-->
<server name="default-server">
  <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
  <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
  </host>
</server>
<!--Сервер, который мы добавили-->
<server name="non-default-server">
  <http-listener name="oteher" socket-binding="http2" redirect-socket="https2"/>
  <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
  </host>
</server>
```

Заметьте, из обоих серверов удалили:

```
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
```

Это нужно для бинда наших приложений к `"/"`

Все. Конфигурацию можно сохранить **Wildfly сервер перезапустить**.

Далее, в самом приложении в каталоге `WEB-INF` необходимо создать файл `jboss-web.xml` со следующим содержимом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <server-instance>non-default-server</server-instance>
</jboss-web>
```

Если `server-instance` не указывать, то приложения будут биндиться к основному серверу

То есть при таком раскладе Ваш сервер будет слушать сразу 2 порта.
Если нужно просто сменить порт и context-root, то задача сводится к редактированию socket-binding и добавлению jboss-web.xml